# Exchanging a variable from a different class between two methods

Tags: java

I'm teaching myself Java and I'm still fairly new but I would just like clarification on calling variables between different methods. I have two methods in a class different from the main class that use the same variable in `taxes`.

First Method:

```
public String getFinalPrice(double taxes, int quantity, double beforeTax){

  double taxValue = taxes;

  double afterPrice = (beforeTax * quantity) * (1+taxes/100);

  return currency.format(afterPrice);

}
```

Second Method:

```
public String getTaxAmount(double taxes, double total){

    total *= (taxes/100);
    return currency.format(total);
}
```

You can see that both of these methods use a `taxes` variable which are the same in terms of the program. Now my question is how can I get the `taxValue` variable from the first method and use it in the second method. How can I get the tax from the user once and put it in the `getFinalPrice` method and then use the `taxValue` variable to take the user input for taxes and get it in the `getTaxAmount` method. I want to essentially get rid of the taxes input for the `getTaxAmount` method:

I would like to change the `getTaxAmount` method to this:

```
public String getTaxAmount(double total){

  total*=(taxValue/100);

  return currency.format(total);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance field called `taxes`, and a third method to change the value of that field. Often in Java, the method to change the value of the field is implemented using the "getter/setter" pattern, in which case the method to change the value is called `set<fieldname>`, in your case: `setTaxes`:

```
public class MyClass {
    private double taxes;

    public void setTaxes(double taxes) {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public String getTaxAmount(double total){

        total*=(taxes/100);

        return currency.format(total);
    }

    public String getFinalPrice(int quantity, double beforeTax){

        double afterPrice = (beforeTax * quantity) * (1+taxes/100);

        return currency.format(afterPrice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to clear your doubt upon multiple declaration of variables, there are two types of scope first is global and second is local.As you can see that you had defined taxes variable in the first method which has a local scope only under get final price outside that method that variable has no existence and when you define taxes in the second method it get existed only for that method . when you define the variable outside any method or block then it got Global scope and hence it existed everywhere in the program.

---

for using the taxValue in other method you can make taxValue a global variable(define outside the method) and then you can use it in other method too.